# AVX2 instruction to handle multiply operations between __m256 types uint32_t and float)

Tags: avx2

Need some directions on AVX2 instructions to handle different types floats and int.
Is there a built-in/existing instruction that can handle the multiplication of the 2 directly.
Or how to effectively do this set of operations? (Trying to optimize for speed, by that i mean end result i would want INT)

__m256 _FourFloats{ 18.364,78.583,15.364,25.367 };

_m256i _FourInt {0xced,0xfed,0xbed,0xaed};

Using 8th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU, which only supports AVX2
VS 2019

Tried looking at Intel AVX page for clues

Comment: No, the only mixed-type multiply in x86 is `pmaddubsw`, between signed and unsigned 8-bit integers.  You'll have to convert one type to the other.  (Preferably to float, since `vmulps` has better throughput than `vpmulld`).  Unsigned to float conversion is hard to do efficiently, but your example unsigned values are all very small, so hopefully you can use a signed conversion that treats them as signed positive.

Comment: The User-Defined Conversion Operator isn't in place
operator _m256( ) const{ } .. so there is no direct conversion within the intrinsic type supported.
I guess, the conversion of unsigned int to float have to be done separately and used the converted value to initialize a  __m256 object

Before calling _mm256_mul_ps(__m256,__m256) that generates the asm vmulpus, right?

Comment: Yes, `_mm256_mul_ps` is the intrinsic for the `vmulps` asm instruction.  Asm mnemonics are much shorter to type so it's what I normally use to talk about them.  The intrinsic for `vcvtdq2ps` (signed 32-bit int to float conversion) is `_mm256_cvtepi32_ps`.  And for converting the FP multiply result to integer, `_mm256_cvtps_epi32`.

Comment: Note that `__m256` holds eight floats; your example only has four, so you'd want `__m128` and  `__m128i` for that, or to make a larger example.